# Debugging an error message from a .net web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have a web service hosted on a server written in `c#`. It's pretty out of the box with some exposed Web Methods. When I hit these web methods locally, they work fine. As soon as my client tries to hit any of them using a test app like `Soap Client` (soapclient.com), or `SoapUI`, they get the following error message returned from the server:

```
We are sorry, the requested operation failed. The server returned the following messages

Error Message: The extern component has failed in processing your requests.
```

I tried googling the error but didn't find any solution that was helpful... so I'm at a bit of a loss here. Anyone have any input on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you looked in the event log or tried enabling more verbose logging?

Comment: How are you hosting the service?  IIS?  What port are you connecting over?  What is the url they are trying to connect with?

Comment: if you are hosting with IIS, try enabling the web request logging hopefully would tell you more.

Comment: Are these WCF or .asmx services?

Comment: .asmx, hosted on IIS. I'm turning on the logging now to see what it says

Comment: What version of IIS are they being deployed to?

Comment: The version of IIS is 6, running on Win server 2k3

Comment: Same issue I am having.. unfortunately no one has solution for it.. Please post the ans if found any.